# Testing if a closure was 'injected" to instance

Tags: grails, groovy

I inject method `afterInsert` to metaClass instance when it `hasProperty("auditable")`

```
def injectMethod(object) {
    if(object.hasProperty("auditable") {
        object.metaClass.afterInsert = { doSomething }
    }
}
```

How can I test that `object` responds to `afterInsert`?

I tried:

```
assert object.respondsTo("afterInsert")
```

and

```
assert object.hasProperty("afterInsert")
```

nothing

```
assert object.metaClass.afterInsert != null // Always true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`metaClass.respondsTo`?

```
class A {
  def foo
}

a = new A()

assert a.hasProperty("foo")
assert !a.metaClass.respondsTo(a, "bar")

a.metaClass.bar = { 10 }

assert a.hasProperty("foo")
assert a.metaClass.respondsTo(a, "bar")

assert a.bar() == 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider asserting as below w.r.t the example:

```
assert object.metaClass.respondsTo(object, "afterInsert")
assert !object.metaClass.respondsTo(object, "beforeInsert")
```

assuming `object` is a Grails Domain class. In case `object` is a base POGO, signature of `hasProperty` can be similar to that of `respondsTo`.